# How can I change button size?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibutton, sprite-kit

I don't know how can I change button size. What should I do? Can anyone tell me that? Here is my code :

```
   let playAgain: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(140, 400, 100, 50))
   playAgain.setTitle("Play Again", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


   playAgain.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
   playAgain.tag = 1
   self.view!.addSubview(playAgain)
```

Comment: When do you plan on changing it?  just keep a copy of playAgain somewhere and change the frame, or pull it out of the subViews when you need to if you do not want to retain playAgain

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change the values of

```
CGRectMake(140, 400, WIDTH_YOU_WANT, HEIGHT_YOU_WANT)
```

To change the font:

`playAgain.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name: "Arial-MT", size: 20)`

Change "Arial-MT" for any System Font you want (careful with the name or it will give you an error).

Comment: I tried. But they just change button's highlight's size. I need change font size  in button.

Comment: I´ve edited my answer answering how to change font size